# Why, despite of using a bulletproof @face-font syntax, I cannot set the font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, local

Trying to use in a span the font saved locally but no results.
This is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'pacifico';
    src: local(C:\Users\ProBook\Dropbox\work\WEBDESIGN\bartCRM\site\pacifico\pacifico.eot) format('eot');
    src: local(C:\Users\ProBook\Dropbox\work\WEBDESIGN\bartCRM\site\pacifico\pacifico.woff) format('woff'),
        local(C:\Users\ProBook\Dropbox\work\WEBDESIGN\bartCRM\site\pacifico\pacifico.ttf) format('truetype'),
        local(C:\Users\ProBook\Dropbox\work\WEBDESIGN\bartCRM\site\pacifico\pacifico.svg) format('svg');
    }

span {
    font-family: 'Pacifico', Courier;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    }
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="text">
<span>a sentence</span>
```

Any ideas on how to make Pacifico font appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this font, but from your machine (doesn't matter if server or just a local PC), just paste this link to browser:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico
```

and copy the code. After this, change a path to this font from

```
http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/pacifico/v5/yunJt0R8tCvMyj_V4xSjafesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff
```

to

```
fonts/yunJt0R8tCvMyj_V4xSjafesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff
```

or wherever you want to keep font file.

Comment: Works for me just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` to your header.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZhXB/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, adding the code to my header helped, thank you! Although it's still not quite clear to my why I have to link anywhere while the font is local:) Anyway, thanks!